# declare a vector of some unknown precision

Tags: c++, types, vector

I want to declare a vector in my `.h` file but depending on the precision of the data I send in I might want the vector to be of type `double` or I might want it to be of type `float`.

```
//tolerances.h

class verySimple{

public:
  verySimple();
  ~verySimple();

  void processTolerances(std::vector<double or float> tolerances);
};
```

Could I get a quick lesson, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear what you want to accomplish, but judging by your example you want a function that can accept either float or double vectors.

You can overload functions in C++:

```
class verySimple{
    public:
      void processTolerances(std::vector<float> tolerances);
      void processTolerances(std::vector<double> tolerances);
};
```

Then the appropriate one will be called depending on the argument.

Or, you can make the function a template:

```
template<typename T>
void processTolerances(std::vector<T> tolerances);
```

Or, if `verySimple` as a whole depends on the type:

```
template<typename T>
class verySimple{
    public:
      void processTolerances(std::vector<T> tolerances);
};
```

Which way to choose depends on the natures of `verySimple` and `processTolerances` - there's no general "best solution".

Answer (score 4):

This is what `template` is for.

You can say `template <typename T> class verySimple` and then `void processTolorances(std::vector<T> tolorances);` to do what you want.

You should check out a tutorial though as templates have a lot of gotchas for the uninitiated.

Comment: Or possibly make the method a template instead of the whole class, if this is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're new to templates get everything working with something that isn't a template (either float or double) before converting it to a template.  Most compiler warnings and errors are less informative when templates are involved.

Comment: Compiler errors are no less informative with templates involved, they're just (_much_) more complicated.

Comment: Well that depends on the compiler.  They may have improved over the years, but I've had to deal with plenty that would only tell you about the error at instantiation time, not at definition time, which would give you no idea where in the templates function/class the error actually occurred.